# Law of cosines in double pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I can't yet explain why equation (8) at [Double Pendulum](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DoublePendulum.html) implies that the square of the magnitude of $\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}$ (where $\vec{v_1}=l_1\dot{\theta_1}\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\vec{v_2}=l_1\dot{\theta_2}\hat{\theta}_2$) is $$v_1^2+v_2^2+2v_1v_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$ instead of $$v_1^2+v_2^2-2v_1v_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2),$$ which should be the case by the law of cosines. How can this be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kinetic energy is defined as
$$
T=\sum T_i\sim\mathbf v_1\cdot\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2\cdot\mathbf v_2\tag{1}
$$
and not 
$$
T\sim\left(\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2\right)\tag{2}
$$
as you claim (*...the square of the magnitude of ...*).

Since Equations (1) through (4) of your link, defining the coordinates $x_i,\,y_i$, return positive values when differentiating with respect to time, e.g.,
$$
\dot{x}_2=l_1\cos\theta_1\dot\theta_1+l_2\cos\theta_2\dot\theta_2,
$$
then all the cross terms are positive and so we must have an additive cosine term.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your argument about positive terms and how they are related to the additive cosine term. Also, why can't $\dot{\theta}_i$ be negative (when the bob swings in the other direction)?

Comment: Well have you tried the math? Differentiate Equations (1) through (4) and see what you get. Each term should have plus signs in it. Taking the dot product of these, you'll see the cosine terms *add* to the kinetic energy.

Comment: And I never said that $\dot\theta_i$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Yes, I did the math and got the result, thanks. I'm wondering though how the geometric approach would work.

Comment: The law of cosines is for a triangle, which we don't have in the double pendulum, so I would guess trying to argue from the similarity of the two resulting equations doesn't quite hold necessarily.

Comment: Actually the law of cosines does work here, which is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018074/law-of-cosines-in-double-pendulum?noredirect=1#comment4145115_2018074